# Android bug with buttons and editText

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I have some android code (textView, editText, button) and I add all strings in string.xml. I call these data in this way:

```
Button vibro;          
setVibro((Button) findViewById(R.id.vibro));     
vibro.setText(getString(R.string.vibro_button));            
vibro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vibro);
```

and also I create set and get method for it. This is one part of my main.xml:

```
<EditText     
    android:id="@+id/editme"       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:text="@string/username"     
    />        

 <Button     
    android:id="@+id/buttons"      
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:text="@string/bfirst"     
    />
```

and this is one part of my string.xml:

```
<string name="bfirst">Register</string>
```

The problem is that I see the buttons and edit text and everything in all my pages. I am sure that I call them in a correct way. But what can cause a problem?

Comment: <string name="bfirst">Register</string>

Comment: This was one part of my string.xml

Answer (score 1):

Is setVibro a method?

Also, try to set this line:

`vibro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vibro);`

before this line:

`vibro.setText(getString(R.string.vibro_button));`

Comment: What about the setVibro? What's that?